# An inequality involving infimums of the scaled $k$-th moment and of a scaled moment-generating function.

Tags: statistics, inequality, supremum-and-infimum, moment-generating-functions

Let $X$ be a non-negative r.v., prove that
\begin{equation}
\inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}_+} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X^k]}{t^k}\leqslant \inf_{\lambda\geqslant 0}\frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]}{e^{\lambda t}},\;\forall t>0.
\end{equation}

I was given the above problem during a class of the advanced statistics course in my university. I tried attempting it as follows:

First, let us rewrite the exponentials on the RHS of the above equation using the Maclaurin expansion:
$$
e^{\lambda X} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda X)^k}{k!}, \quad e^{\lambda t} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}.
$$
$X$ being non-negative allows us to expand the expectation of $e^{\lambda X}$ as follows:
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda X)^k}{k!}\right] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k\mathbb{E}X^k}{k!}.
$$
Now, we can write:
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}e^{\lambda X}}{e^{\lambda t}} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^k\mathbb{E}X^k}{k!}}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_\lambda(k)\mathbb{E}X^k}{\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_\lambda(k)t^k},\;\text{where } c_\lambda(k)=\lambda^k/k!
$$

But then I got completely stuck. I can see that now we have $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$ in the numerator-placed series and $t^k$ in the denominator-placed series, both are dynamically scaled by $c_\lambda(k)$, and I don't see how we can relate them. Eventually, I thought that taking infimum over $\lambda$ can be the key, as we will minimize the fraction only over the $\lambda$-dependent $c_\lambda(k)$, but as I see that doesn't really help me much.

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already noted that $$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}] = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{\lambda^k \mathbb{E}X^k}{k!}$$
which can further be written as $$\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]=\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{\mathbb{E}X^k}{t^k} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!} \ge \left(\inf_{k\in \mathbb{Z}_+}  \frac{\mathbb{E}X^k}{t^k} \right)\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!} =\left(\inf_{k\in \mathbb{Z}_+}  \frac{\mathbb{E}X^k}{t^k} \right)e^{\lambda t} $$
so dividing through by $e^{\lambda t}$ and taking an infimum over $\lambda \ge 0$ gives the result.

Comment: Oh thank you! How could I miss such a logical construction?